# Negative Log Likelihood of a Gaussian Model can be negative?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, probability

I am confused about the negative log likelihood of a guassian model:

[image]

Can the negative likelihood of a gaussian model  be negative ?
lets suppose that the variance is going to 0 faster than the MSE the first term (log \sigma(xi)^2) will go to minus infinity.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't missing anything. The negative log-likelihood of any distribution can be negative.

In the case of the **negative** log-likelihood for a Gaussian random variable, this occurs when the function is evaluated at a particular $y_i$ that is highly probable given $\mu(x_i)$ and $\sigma(x_i)$, i.e. when $\mu(x_i)$ is reasonably close to $y_i$ and $\sigma(x_i)$ is sufficiently small. Positive values occur in the opposite case, when the (fitted) model described by $\mu(x_i)$ and $\sigma(x_i)$ gives low density to $y_i$ (i.e. a poor probabilistic prediction).

Note that in maximum likelihood estimation, the goal is to maximize the likelihood function, not the negative likelihood function. If you throw a negative sign in front, of course this switches the objective to minimizing, in which case, highly negative values of the negative log-likelihood are preferred.

Your observation about the function possibly tending to infinity is also highly relevant; in fact, this is why the [log scoring rule (often called ELPD in Bayesian statistics) can behave quite unstable in practice.](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/research/published/loo_stan.pdf)

Comment: thank you very much for this insight !